# Print/paste newline every X element in a vector

Tags: r

I'm looking to format the output of a vector to print on a newline every X element.

For example, let's say I want to print through every 4th letter of the alphabet and to format the output:

```
'A', 'B', 'C', 'D',
'E', 'F', 'G', 'H',
'I', 'J', 'K', 'L',
'M', 'N', 'O', 'P',
'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T',
'U', 'V', 'W', 'X',
'Y', 'Z'
```

Here's what I've tried that hasn't worked because I'm not able to print through to the end of the vector.

```
start_range <- 1
for (i in 1:length(LETTERS)){
  if (i %% 4 == 0){
    print(paste0(LETTERS[start_range:i], collapse = "', '"))
    start_range <- start_range + 4
  }

}

# Output 
'A', 'B', 'C', 'D',
'E', 'F', 'G', 'H',
'I', 'J', 'K', 'L',
'M', 'N', 'O', 'P',
'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T',
'U', 'V', 'W', 'X',
```

Misses 'Y' and 'Z'.  This approach is obviously wrong, what's a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following will do it.
Sorry for the name of the function, say so and I will edit it.

```
james <- function(x, n = 4){
    chunks <- length(x) %/% n
    for (i in seq_len(chunks)){
        cat(paste0("'", x[(n*(i - 1) + 1):(n*i)], "'", collapse = ", "), "\n")
    }
    cat(paste0("'", x[(n*i + 1):length(x)], "'", collapse = ", "), "\n")
}

james(LETTERS)
#'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' 
#'E', 'F', 'G', 'H' 
#'I', 'J', 'K', 'L' 
#'M', 'N', 'O', 'P' 
#'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T' 
#'U', 'V', 'W', 'X' 
#'Y', 'Z'
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
lst <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D',
'E', 'F', 'G', 'H',
'I', 'J', 'K', 'L',
'M', 'N', 'O', 'P',
'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T',
'U', 'V', 'W', 'X',
'Y', 'Z')

print(lst[seq(1:length(lst)) %% 4 == 0])

[1] "D" "H" "L" "P" "T" "X"
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. He wanted to print with a newline following every 4th letter. Though I can see where the confusion came from " I want to print through every 4th letter of the alphabet"